# How to send send json and multipart file in postman both having @RequestPart annotation in controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman, multipartform-data, multipart

I have developed a code which takes input Json and Multipart file as input. But, when I am trying to call this API in postman, I am getting error as:

> Required request part 'input' is not present"

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/saveThumbnail"}, method={RequestMethod.POST},  
            consumes={"multipart/form-data"}, headers={"Accept=application/json"}) 
    public ImageConversionOutput convertImageIntoThumbnail(@RequestPart ImageConversionInput input, @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
    {
        ImageConversionService service = new ImageConversionService();
        System.out.println(input);
        ImageConversionOutput  output = null;
        try {
             output = service.convertImageToThumbnail(input, file, imageRepository);
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output;

    }
```

My postman Request is as follows:

[image: Request Headers]

[image: Request parameters]

I am getting below error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your `input` param in json format? 
Try `{"fileName": "test7", "fileType": "png", "barCodeFlag":"F"}`

---

[**@RequestPart**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html)

> while RequestPart is likely to be used with parts containing more complex content e.g. JSON, XML).

**Request** :

```
//file: request.js    

var form = new FormData();
// user is a json string, not an object.
form.append('user', JSON.stringify({name: 'John', age: 18})); 
// append the file
form.append('file', file));
```

**Controller** :

```
@PostMapping("/saveUser")
public User saveUser(
    @RequestPart(value = "user") UserProfile user, 
    @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
{
    // code..
}
```